# Laplace inverse transform with Fourier Series Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, math, transform, symbols

I have a code for the inverse Laplace transform based on the Fourier Series algorithm. Lets say I need to find the inverse Laplace transform of the below function at t=1:

f = 1/(s-1)

The inverse Laplace transform of f is : e^(t)

At t=1 the result is = e.  Here is my code and in this case it works well.

```
from  numpy import *

M = 11
SU = zeros(M + 2)
C = zeros(M + 1)
C[0] = 1
for k in range(1, M + 1):
    C[k] = (M - (k - 1)) * C[k-1] / k
T = 1
A = 19.1
Ntr = 15
U = exp(A / 2.0) / T
X = A / (2.0 * T)
H = pi / T

def fnRf(X, Y):
  S = complex(X, Y)
  Fs = 1.0 / (S - 1)
  Rfs = real(Fs)
  return Rfs

Sum = fnRf(X, 0) / 2.0
for N in range(1, Ntr + 1):
    Y = N * H
    Sum += (-1) ** N * fnRf(X, Y)

SU[0] = Sum
for K in range(1, M + 2):
  N = Ntr + K
  Y = N * H
  SU[K] = SU[K-1] + (-1)**N * fnRf(X, Y)

Avgsu = 0.0
Avgsu1 = 0.0
for J in range(M + 1):
  Avgsu += C[J] * SU[J]
  Avgsu1 += C[J] * SU[J+1]
Fun= U * Avgsu / 2048
Fun1= U * Avgsu1 / 2048

print Fun1
```

But I want to do a little more complicated thing here. In this code here is where I have defined my function in the Laplace domain:

```
Fs=1./(S-1)
```

I need to include a variable (or a Symbol) in the function in the Laplace domain and I need to keep that variable when I transfer my function from the Laplace domain to the time domain. For example:

**f = C*1/(s-1)**

In this case I want to transfer the above function from the Laplace domain to the time domain and **C** is an unknown variable. I want to know how I can transfer such a function to the time domain. **I expect to get something with respect to the C in the time domain**. I have already tried something but I got some weird errors. Could you please tell me how I can do such thing in this code? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I think the fastest way to get the answer you want is by simplifying the question. Your problem seems to be a simple enough coding problem, but its obfuscated by the complex mathematics of your application. Could you boil what you want down into a simpler example?

Comment: Let me explain a little more about what I want to do: I want to optimize the constant "C" after I transfer my function from Laplace domain to the time domain. It mean when I transfer my function to the time domain I need to have "C" constant. Otherwise I am not able to optimize it.